# Error in my logout section of my program in C#, can i get some help?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, logout

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[Flags]
public enum ExitWindows : uint
{
    LogOff = 0x00,
    Force = 0x04,
}

[Flags]
enum ShutdownReason : uint
{
    MajorApplication = 0x00040000,
    MajorHardware = 0x00010000,
    MajorLegacyApi = 0x00070000,
    MajorOperatingSystem = 0x00020000,
    MajorOther = 0x00000000,
    MajorPower = 0x00060000,
    MajorSoftware = 0x00030000,
    MajorSystem = 0x00050000,

    MinorBlueScreen = 0x0000000F,
    MinorCordUnplugged = 0x0000000b,
    MinorDisk = 0x00000007,
    MinorEnvironment = 0x0000000c,
    MinorHardwareDriver = 0x0000000d,
    MinorHotfix = 0x00000011,
    MinorHung = 0x00000005,
    MinorInstallation = 0x00000002,
    MinorMaintenance = 0x00000001,
    MinorMMC = 0x00000019,
    MinorNetworkConnectivity = 0x00000014,
    MinorNetworkCard = 0x00000009,
    MinorOther = 0x00000000,
    MinorOtherDriver = 0x0000000e,
    MinorPowerSupply = 0x0000000a,
    MinorProcessor = 0x00000008,
    MinorReconfig = 0x00000004,
    MinorSecurity = 0x00000013,
    MinorSecurityFix = 0x00000012,
    MinorSecurityFixUninstall = 0x00000018,
    MinorServicePack = 0x00000010,
    MinorServicePackUninstall = 0x00000016,
    MinorTermSrv = 0x00000020,
    MinorUnstable = 0x00000006,
    MinorUpgrade = 0x00000003,
    MinorWMI = 0x00000015,

    FlagUserDefined = 0x40000000,
    FlagPlanned = 0x80000000
}


class class1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ExitWindows(int uFlags, int dwReason);
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            class1
                ExitWindows(0,00)//*i get an error here saying the int has been declared but not used
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: First: why don't you use formatting? select all your code lines and press CTRL-K, its as easy as that. Second: It would help a lot if you post the type of error you are experiencing

Comment: What errors are you getting? other than no match found for extern I can't see a error that can come up here

Comment: All you have to do is indent the code lines with 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button on the editing toolbar. You don't have to use any HTML.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that you have to define the `ExitWindowsEx` function **inside of a class**. C# doesn't support free functions like C++ does. Teoman's solution will work, but it's important to know what was wrong with your original code so you can learn something, too.

Comment: @Brian, I had a typo in the sample. Change `ShutdownReason.MajorOther & ShutdownReason.MinorOther` to `ShutdownReason.MajorOther | ShutdownReason.MinorOther`. Thanks to Cody spotting it.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
class Class1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, uint dwReason);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExitWindowsEx(ExitWindows.LogOff, ShutdownReason.MajorOther | ShutdownReason.MinorOther);
        //this will cause the computer to logoff.
    }
}
```

Where the flags are:

```
[Flags]
public enum ExitWindows : uint
{
   // ONE of the following five:
   LogOff = 0x00,
   ShutDown = 0x01,
   Reboot = 0x02,
   PowerOff = 0x08,
   RestartApps = 0x40,
   // plus AT MOST ONE of the following two:
   Force = 0x04,
   ForceIfHung = 0x10,
}

[Flags]
enum ShutdownReason : uint
{
    MajorApplication = 0x00040000,
    MajorHardware = 0x00010000,
    MajorLegacyApi = 0x00070000,
    MajorOperatingSystem = 0x00020000,
    MajorOther = 0x00000000,
    MajorPower = 0x00060000,
    MajorSoftware = 0x00030000,
    MajorSystem = 0x00050000,

    MinorBlueScreen = 0x0000000F,
    MinorCordUnplugged = 0x0000000b,
    MinorDisk = 0x00000007,
    MinorEnvironment = 0x0000000c,
    MinorHardwareDriver = 0x0000000d,
    MinorHotfix = 0x00000011,
    MinorHung = 0x00000005,
    MinorInstallation = 0x00000002,
    MinorMaintenance = 0x00000001,
    MinorMMC = 0x00000019,
    MinorNetworkConnectivity = 0x00000014,
    MinorNetworkCard = 0x00000009,
    MinorOther = 0x00000000,
    MinorOtherDriver = 0x0000000e,
    MinorPowerSupply = 0x0000000a,
    MinorProcessor = 0x00000008,
    MinorReconfig = 0x00000004,
    MinorSecurity = 0x00000013,
    MinorSecurityFix = 0x00000012,
    MinorSecurityFixUninstall = 0x00000018,
    MinorServicePack = 0x00000010,
    MinorServicePackUninstall = 0x00000016,
    MinorTermSrv = 0x00000020,
    MinorUnstable = 0x00000006,
    MinorUpgrade = 0x00000003,
    MinorWMI = 0x00000015,

    FlagUserDefined = 0x40000000,
    FlagPlanned = 0x80000000
}
```

Comment: The `&` should be an `|`. You don't combine flags with a logical AND, you combine them with a logical OR.

Comment: @Cody Gray, yes you're right. I fall for that all the time. Corrected the sample.

Answer (score 0):

uFlags should be unsigned. Try with a uint.